# Visual Studio 2012 - Postgresql using psqlODBC driver wrong row count

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2012

ok guys im using psqlODBC driver 09.02.0100 to connect postgres with visual studio 2012.

I have the following code in my form who call a function in my clsConnection class like this:

```
Dim id As String = ""
id = objcon.bringId(txtCompany.Text)
```

I already check and the connection to the db is ok. So if you look in the class function i write a console.write command to check how many rows brings from the database.

Well debugging  the app step by step i grab the sqlcommand and paste in Postgresql and get one single result (should be like that!)

But when the rows.count execute it trows me a count of 40!!!! im waiting only 1 result.....

Anyone can help me please

```
Public Function bringId(companyName As String) As String
    Dim id As String = ""
    Try
        connectionBD.Open()
        SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT ""idCom"" FROM company where ""nameCom"" = '" & companyName  & "';"
        DBdataAdapter.SelectCommand = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(SQLcommand.CommandText, conetionBD)
        DBdataAdapter.Fill(myDbDataset)
        Console.Write(myDbDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
        connectionBD.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Db error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection error")
    End Try
    Return id
End Function
```

Comment: Please post that as an answer to your own question when the timer will let you then comment here. I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys after a lot of try i find that i have to "clean" the dataset for every time i use it like this myDbDataset.Clear() I have to do this before every DBdataAdapter.Fill(myDbDataset) If i dont do that the dtset fills with information requested in old querys